# Tying in to existing hardwood flooring

Tags: flooring

I'm getting ready to lay down hardwood flooring in a bedroom that is the same as what was previously layed in the hallway outside of the bedroom.  There was carpeting in this bedroom before.

I layed the flooring in the hallway earlier and ended at the doorway of the bedroom with a piece I cut to meet where the carpet ended.

[image: Hallway floor end]

However, if I start a new row directly adjacent to this doorway piece in the bedroom, it gets offset by a small amount when I leave the required gap by the drywall.

[image: Floor when next to wall]

And here is picture with what that gap would be when I'd line the piece up with the wall.

[image: Gap in floor by hallway]

What's the best way to do this?  I can remove the piece in the doorway if I need to.  The other way I see is to cut the wall-side of each piece along the wall so that it lines up with the doorway piece.  I do have access to woodworking tools: tablesaw etc.

Comment: When you cut the piece in the doorway, how much did you cut off? Would everything line up nice if you replaced that piece?

Comment: I don't remember, it's been 3 years or so.  Looking at it, it looks like I took off not quite half of the width.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to rip the starting board to match what's protruding into the bedroom. First establish an accurate straight line based on the existing flooring. You may need to taper the starter to fit an out-of-square or curved wall.

Update: I didn't initially catch that you had ripped the final board in the doorway. That board should be removed and replaced with a full board.

Comment: So then all the pieces along the wall thereafter would be ripped to hit that line?  If so I think I understand..

Comment: Yep. Just as you'll (probably) have to cut every other board that encounters a wall.

Answer (score 0):

Lay the piece against the wall door jamb the draw a pencil mark across the floorboard along the door jamb.  At this point I use a sonic tool to cut the jamb back so the floor slided right inder with a 1/16 inch gap between the floor surface and the door jamb for expansion. But they make saws in the flooring section of any store that are drop set, or up could jut whittle it☺.